# Why isn't systemd running my ExecStartPre script?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, sh

I have two graphics cards, and need to configure xorg to use the right card based on the boot option I select in grub. To achieve this, I've added an arbitrary string to the kernel params of one boot option ("FORCENVIDIA" in this case), and I have a script that checks for the presence of that string and then symlinks a .conf file to one of two other files based on whether or not it's present:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

if cat /proc/cmdline | grep FORCENVIDIA > /dev/null; then
        rm -f /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/old-config
        cp /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-force-gpu.conf /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/old-config
        rm -f /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-force-gpu.conf
        ln -s /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/XX-force-nvidia /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-force-gpu.conf
else
        rm -f /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/old-config
        cp /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-force-gpu.conf /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/old-config
        rm -f /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-force-gpu.conf
        ln -s /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/XX-force-amd /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-force-gpu.conf
fi
```

So if FORCENVIDIA is in /proc/cmdline, it deletes whatever the old .conf is and recreates it symlinking to XX-force-nvidia (which obviously contains the right setup for my nvidia card). If FORCENVIDIA is NOT in /proc/cmdline, it does the same thing for XX-force-amd.

To make this run before X starts, I've included it as an ExecStartPre for my display manager - sddm by using `sudo systemctl edit sddm.service` to create a drop in config like so:

```
[Service]
# select the primary GPU to display X
ExecStartPre=@/bin/sh /usr/share/select_primary_card.sh
```

and I can use `systemctl status sddm.service` to verify that systemd *thinks* it's running that:

```
● sddm.service - Simple Desktop Display Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/sddm.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/sddm.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-05-28 06:28:36 BST; 9min ago
     Docs: man:sddm(1)
           man:sddm.conf(5)
 Main PID: 1350 (sddm)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/sddm.service
           ├─1350 /usr/bin/sddm
           └─1352 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -nolisten tcp -auth /var/run/sddm/{eea7054b-d749-4569-9c3f-e44f13be8942} -background none -noreset -displayfd 18 -seat seat0 vt1

May 28 06:30:55 PC sddm-helper[1731]: Starting: "/etc/sddm/Xsession \"/usr/bin/startkde\""
May 28 06:30:56 PC sddm[1350]: Auth: sddm-helper exited successfully
May 28 06:30:56 PC sddm[1350]: Greeter stopped.
May 28 06:30:56 PC sddm[1350]: Session started                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
May 28 06:30:57 PC sddm[1350]: Checking for pam module                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
May 28 06:30:57 PC sddm[1350]: Got pam-login                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
May 28 06:30:57 PC sddm[1350]: kwalletd: Waiting for hash on 15-                                                                                                                                                                                                               
May 28 06:30:57 PC sddm[1350]: kwalletd: waitingForEnvironment on: 3                                                                                                                                                                                                           
May 28 06:30:57 PC sddm[1350]: kwalletd: client connected                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
May 28 06:30:57 PC sddm[1350]: kwalletd: client disconnected
```

The problem is, it's **not** running. In the script I included lines to copy the existing .conf file to a file called "old-config", so that I can see what the conf file looked like on the previous boot (the nvidia boot option doesn't work and it's difficult to diagnose when you reboot to the working one and it replaces the .conf). That old-config file doesn't exist when I boot and log in. As far as I can tell though, the script is fine. If I manually run it with `sudo /usr/share/select_primary_card.sh` it seems to do what it should.

Can anyone see what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the `@` prefix, which means the */bin/sh* executable will receive this argument list:

```
{[0] = "/usr/share/select_primary_card.sh"}
```

instead of the expected one:

```
{[0] = "/bin/sh", [1] = "/usr/share/select_primary_card.sh"}
```

By convention, the zeroth item in the argument list always contains the program's own name and is more or less ignored by most software.

But when scripts are being run through an interpreter, argv[0] contains the *interpreter's* name, and the path to script is normally item #1 – i.e. just a regular part of the interpreter's command line. So when the `@` is used, /bin/sh thinks it's being run with an empty command line and tries to go into interactive mode, fails, and exits.

You **do not** need any special argv[0] trickery in order to run a script. Just run it either like this (honoring the `#!` header):

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/share/select_primary_card.sh
```

or like this (bypassing the `#!` header):

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh /usr/share/select_primary_card.sh
```

As a side note, don't put your custom configurations in /usr/share – that's what /etc/X11 is for.

Comment: herpaderp - misread the systemd.service documentation there. Thank you very much, we have progress. And yes, I realised I'd put them in the wrong place after reading the man pages - I shall move them now it's all working (was wary of fiddling with stuff till I'd identified what was broken). Thanks for the help.